# how we can convert a project written en c++ to dll file?

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, tesseract

I have a project written en c++ in which i use tesseract and opencv libraries.

the project contain one function which return an Int ant it has as parameter sting an int

```
    int image_blanche(string nom_img,double k);
```

My question how can i convert it to dll file to use it in an other .net project

Comment: yes and it works without error

Comment: Change the build type to dll from the project properties and build.

Comment: By going to the project proprties menu, build option, and changing it from .EXE to .DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a header file (e.g. "Defines.h") containing:

```
#pragma once
#ifdef COREDLL_EXPORTS
#define COREDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define COREDLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif
```

Your function should then be defined in a header like this:

```
#include "Defines.h"
extern "C"
{
    COREDLL_API int image_blanche(char const* nom_img,double k);
};
```

...and implemented in a source file.

Compile that Project with COREDLL_EXPORTS defined as a DLL Project and use the dll in another project.

When building the DLL having COREDLL_EXPORTS defined you basically produce (=export) the symbols and place them in the DLL. When using the DLL in another project not having COREDLL_EXPORTS defined, you consuming/reading (=import) the symbols from the DLL.

Here is a good explanation of how you can then invoke the function from the DLL: [Dynamic Invoke C++ DLL function in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27298/Dynamic-Invoke-C-DLL-function-in-C)

**Update:** As MSalters correctly pointed out, using C-Style datatypes should be considered, as it plays friendly across DLL bounds. I changed the string parameter to use a character array instead.

Comment: what does it means extern "C"

Comment: extern "C" makes a function-name in C++ have 'C' linkage (compiler does not mangle the name).

Comment: Downvoted, as `extern "C"` is a particular bad idea for a function which takes a `std::string`. You absolutely want name mangling there. When the name mangling causes a linker error, it almost certainly prevented a runtime error in the interpretation of the `std::string` class,